# Center material design text field

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have the following html code:

```html
<div class="mdc-text-field steps_div" id="textfeild">       
  <input type="number" class="mdc-text-field__input" id="steps" name="name">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="steps">Steps</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

This CSS centers the text box:

```css
div#textfeild {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```css
.steps_div {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Why does the first works and the second doesn't?

Comment: I see with both css the code works! I don't see the difference.

Comment: If the id works and class doesn't work, probably you are having a CSS specificity issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using an **id** in CSS has higher priority than **class**.
In your case **div#textfeild** has more weight to css than **.steps_div**.

Even if you use **.steps_div** after **div#textfeild** - the first one will be leader, because of the weight and unique quality of **id**.